# Cannot create outlet for View in prototype cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, swift4, iboutlet

I want to create a prototype cell with rounded corners and a colored background that can be changed during runtime. In order to do this, I put a View object in the cell content view and put labels inside the View. Note that I did all of this in storyboard. To be able to change the background color of the View, I need an outlet to access it during runtime. However, I can create neither a string nor a weak outlet of the View inside my UITableViewCell class.

When I create a weak outlet, it gives me following errors:

> Cannot override 'strong' property with 'weak' property Getter for
>   'backgroundView' with Objective-C selector 'backgroundView' conflicts
>   with getter for 'backgroundView' from superclass 'UITableViewCell'
>   with the same Objective-C selector Property 'backgroundView' with type
>   'UIView?' cannot override a property with type 'UIView?' Setter for
>   'backgroundView' with Objective-C selector 'setBackgroundView:'
>   conflicts with setter for 'backgroundView' from superclass
>   'UITableViewCell' with the same Objective-C selector

These errors appear together. And when 
I tried to create a strong outlet, it gives me following error:

> Cannot override with a stored property 'backgroundView' Getter for
>   'backgroundView' with Objective-C selector 'backgroundView' conflicts
>   with getter for 'backgroundView' from superclass 'UITableViewCell'
>   with the same Objective-C selector Setter for 'backgroundView' with
>   Objective-C selector 'setBackgroundView:' conflicts with setter for
>   'backgroundView' from superclass 'UITableViewCell' with the same
>   Objective-C selector

I am confused right now. Is it by default that we cannot create an outlet for View object in prototype cell or is it some other reason?

Comment: Share your `TableViewCell`'s code for better help.

Comment: You cannot use the property name `backgroundView`, which is defined in `UITableViewCell`. Use another name.

Comment: Thanks OOPer , you saved me much confusion!